# JavaScript - Disable console messages from third-party libraries

Tags: javascript

I'm working to improve an existing site. This site integrates some third-party libraries. Unfortunately, these third-party libraries write various logs to the console window like the following:

```
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 30ms.
[Report Only] Refused to frame '...' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

I would like to disable these messages in my production environment. Unfortunately, the libraries do not seem to provide a setting or function to turn these logs off. I was hoping to override the log statements in *my* code. In an effort to do this, at the top of my web page, I have:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log = function() { };
    console.warn = function() { };
    console.error = function() { };
  </script>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

While my `console` override functions are declared before the third-party libraries are loaded, I still see them in the console. How do I get prevent any and all messages getting written to the console window?

Thank you!

Comment: Those aren't coming from the third-party libraries, they're coming from Chrome itself.

Comment: @Barmar is there a way to disable / hide them via JavaScript?

Comment: I can find lots of answers saying how the user can filter them. I can't find anything mentioning a way that JS can do that.